# extract a base directory from the output of ps

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am looking to extract a basedir from the output of `ps -ef | grep classpath myprog.jar`

```
root  20925 20886  1 17:41 pts/0  00:01:07 /opt/myprog/java/jre/bin -classpath myprog.jar
```

java is always a sub-dir under the basedir *but* the install path can vary from server to server e.g.

```
/usr/local/myprog/java/jre/bin

/opt/test/testing/myprog/java/jre/bin
```

So once i have my string how do I extract everything from **before** java *until* the beginning of the path?

That is, `/usr/local/myprog` or `/opt/test/testing/myprog/`

Comment: Sorry @gniourf_gniourf, I guess we both edited at the same time. Please feel free to make changes where you think is right. I modified the expected output appropriately as OP's output didn't sync up with what he was asking.

Comment: @JS웃 Don't worry, our edits were pretty much equivalent! (and yours is actually more accurate).

Comment: `ps axo args` will list the full command (including path) of every process on the system.  This is the BSD-style format specifiers to `ps`, so should mostly work on Linux and OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
$ echo "root  20925 20886  1 17:41 pts/0  00:01:07 /opt/myprog/java/jre/bin -classpath myprog.jar" | sed 's/.*\ \(.*\)\/java.*/\1/'
/opt/myprog
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -P`:

```
ps -ef | grep -oP '\S+(?=/java)'
/opt/myprog
```

If your grep doesn't support `-P` then use:

```
s='root  20925 20886  1 17:41 pts/0  00:01:07 /opt/myprog/java/jre/bin -classpath myprog.jar'
[[ "$s" =~ (/[^[:blank:]]+)/java ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
/opt/myprog
```

Comment: returns returns /opt/myprog/java/jre/bin

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "root  20925 20886  1 17:41 pts/0  00:01:07 /opt/myprog/java/jre/bin -classpath myprog.jar" | awk '{split($8,a,"/java"); print a[1]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pgrep` to find all of the Java processes instead of using `ps -ef | grep ...`. This way, you don't have to worry about your `grep` command showing up as one of your items.

Instead of running `ps -ef`, you can use the `-o` option to only pull up the desired fields, and most `ps` commands take `--no-header` to eliminate the header fields. This way, your script doesn't have to worry about header lines.

Finally, I am using [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) which is sometimes way easier than using `sed` to change a variable:

```
$ ps -o pid,args --no-headers $(pgrep -f "java .* myproj.jar") | while read pid command arguments
do
    directory=${command%/java*}
    echo "The directory for Process ID $pid is $directory"
done
```

By the way, you could be running multiple commands, so I loop through the `ps` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps axo args | awk '/classpath myprog.jar/{print substr($0, 0,index($0, "java")-1)}'
```

For example:

```
$ echo '/opt/myprog/java/jre/bin -classpath myprog.jar' \
  | awk '/classpath myprog.jar/{print substr($0, 0,index($0, "java")-1)}'
/opt/myprog/
```

You can (and probably should) switch both of the `$0`'s to `$1`'s if you know for sure that your path will not contain spaces.  Or add additional fields to the ps -o list using commas (as in, `o pid,args`) and use `$2` rather than `$1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can match the following regex:

`'((\/\w+)+)\/java'`

and the first captured group `\1` or `$1` will contain the wanted string

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/zU2vV4

Comment: This demonstrates that you know regex but doesn't provide an answer to the question.